# Why HTTPs is not supported in Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

While parsing an API I noticed that when I am using https there is Chain validation failed message. I used this to solve the problem: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true". But my question is why I need to use this?

Comment: I recommend that you provide a [mcve] showing your code and the complete stack trace of your error.

Comment: Retrofit most definitely support HTTPS. You most likely made a mistake in configuring the request

Comment: Actually when you set that attribute to true, it means something in the app is using http instead of https. This has nothing to do with Retrofit. You should double check all your network requests.